# sqlite: how to get a count of group counts

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table of user actions on a website.  Each row is the same action on a web site, just different time/date, tagged with a user id.  The table has more than 20Million entries. I understand how to get a count by user (i.e. A took the action 3 times, B 4, C 2, D 4, etc.) using the group by function by user id.  In other words this works fine:

```
select count(uid) as event_count
from table
group by uid
```

What I want is the data for a statistical distribution which is a count of the number of users who only took 1 action, a count of users that took 2 actions, etc.  Said another way: The list might look something like:

```
1 | 339,440
2 | 452,555
3 | 99,239
5 | 20,209
etc. ...
```

I could use the `having event_count = n` clause and just rerun the query for every integer until all were accounted for but that seems silly.  There must be a way that I can get a single list with two columns: the group size  and the count of the users who all took the exact same number of actions.

Comment: Why not to group your results by count?

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Can you show by way of example how to arrive at your result?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Say you have 100 events that were created by 60 users.  Some created 1 of those event, some created 5, some created 3.  In the previous sentence I want to know how many each "some" is.  Giorgi's answer below gets these counts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As simply as adding another grouping above:

```
select event_count, count(*) as users_count
from
(select count(uid) as event_count
 from table
 group by uid) t
group by event_count
order by event_count
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Precisely what I needed.  Thank you!