# Returning count for each id in table

Tags: sqlite, node-sqlite3

Im using sqlite3 with my node.js API.

I have a DB talbe structured below:

```
id | colour
___|_______
1  |  blue
1  |  red
1  |  green
2  |  yellow
2  |  green
5  |  red
```

I want to return a count of the IDs in my table such that

```
1 - 3 occurences
2 - 2 occurences 
5 - 1 occurence
```

Is there a sql qualifier I can use count like this, or will this need to be done within the js iteself?

Any help here would be awesome!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite: how to get a count of group counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705820/sqlite-how-to-get-a-count-of-group-counts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`

```
select id, COUNT(id) from tbl GROUP BY id
```